how to customize hover in react native web?
In this react native web component I'm trying to customize the TouchableRipple effect to add a green border on hover:
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Pressable, View } from "react-native"
import { Surface, Text, TouchableRipple } from "react-native-paper"
import { colors } from "../../style/colors"

interface OptionItemMenuProps {
    section: {
        title: string
        data: {
            option: string
        }[]
    }[]
}

export const OptionItemMenu: React.FC<OptionItemMenuProps> = ({ section }) => {

    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)

    return (
        <View>
            {section.map((option) => (
                <View key={option.title} style={{ gap: 2 }}>
                    <Text style={{ color: colors.grey, marginBottom: 5 }}>{option.title}</Text>
                    {option.data.map((item) => (
                        <TouchableRipple
                            key={item.option}
                            onPress={() => console.log("teste")}
                            onHoverIn={() => setHover(true)}
                            onHoverOut={() => setHover(false)}
                            style={[
                                { paddingVertical: 5, paddingLeft: 5, borderRadius: 5 },
                                hover && { borderColor: colors.primary, borderWidth: 1, paddingVertical: 4, paddingLeft: 4 },
                            ]}
                        >
                            <Text>{item.option}</Text>
                        </TouchableRipple>
                    ))}
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    )
}

but the problem is that when I set hover to true, the style is applied to all items in the map list, as can be seen in the image below:
image of unwanted behavior
I've already tried controlling the hover state with events:
onHoverIn and onHoverOut;
onPointerEnter and onPointerLeave;
How can I customize hover individually?

It’s because each option item needed it’s own hover state; so if you moved the touchable ripple into its own component and created the hover state there then it’d work

I think it’s better to do it that way because the answer you provided will cause all options to re render when one item is hovered

tks, i'll try it later.

I solved it this way:
interface OptionItemMenuProps {
    section: {
        title: string
        data: {
            option: string
        }[]
    }[]
}

export const OptionItemMenu: React.FC<OptionItemMenuProps> = ({ section }) => {
    const [hoverStates, setHoverStates] = useState<{ [key: string]: boolean }>({})

    const handleMouseEnter = (key: string) => {
        setHoverStates((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: true }))
    }

    const handleMouseLeave = (key: string) => {
        setHoverStates((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: false }))
    }

    return (
        <View>
            {section.map((option) => (
                <View key={option.title} style={{ gap: 2 }}>
                    <Text style={{ color: colors.grey, marginBottom: 5 }}>{option.title}</Text>
                    {option.data.map((item) => (
                        <TouchableRipple
                            key={item.option}
                            onPress={() => console.log("teste")}
                            onHoverIn={() => handleMouseEnter(`${item.option}`)}
                            onHoverOut={() => handleMouseLeave(`${item.option}`)}
                            style={[
                                { paddingVertical: 5, paddingLeft: 5, borderRadius: 5 },
                                hoverStates[`${item.option}`] && { borderColor: colors.primary, borderWidth: 1, paddingVertical: 4, paddingLeft: 4 },
                            ]}
                        >
                            <Text>{item.option}</Text>
                        </TouchableRipple>
                    ))}
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    )
}

I created an individual control state:
const [hoverStates, setHoverStates] = useState<{ [key: string]: boolean }

With these functions I control the state of each item:
const handleMouseEnter = (key: string) => {
    setHoverStates((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: true }))
}

const handleMouseLeave = (key: string) => {
    setHoverStates((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: false }))
}

here I change the state:
onHoverIn={() => handleMouseEnter(`${item.option}`)}
onHoverOut={() => handleMouseLeave(`${item.option}`)}

here I check the status and style accordingly:
hoverStates[`${item.option}`] && { borderColor: colors.primary, borderWidth: 1, paddingVertical: 4, paddingLeft: 4 },

This is how I managed to solve it, but if anyone knows how to solve it another way, feel free to post it here
